# How with fullcalendarV5 hide/show items depending on number of events?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

With fullcalendarV5 I have cells with text :"+1 more"/"+2 more" and
looking like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vigxq.jpg
I set options :

```
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        height: 900,
        showNonCurrentDates: false,

        displayEventTime: false,
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: true,
        selectable: true, // can select any cell
        selectOverlap: false,
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        aspectRatio: 0.4,
        ...
```

If there is a way to show text(with hidden items) "+1 more" say If I have 5 or more events a day
and in case of 4 or less show all items ?

**UPDATED # 1 :**
I found property

```
   dayMaxEvents: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
```

and it works for me if to change this value

But other related property dayMaxEventRows (I found here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayMaxEventRows)
does not work for me: I always "more" link . My calendar defintion :

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    height: 900,
    showNonCurrentDates: false,

    displayEventTime: false,
    editable: true,
    allDaySlot: true,
    selectable: true, // can select any cell
    selectOverlap: false,
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    aspectRatio: 0.4,


    customButtons: {
        myCustomButton: {
            text: 'Filter', click: function () {
                window.axios.get('/admin/get_search_info', {}).then((response) => {
                    ...
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error)
                    popupAlert('Calendar', 'Run time error : ' + getErrorMessage(error), 'error')
                })
            }
        }
    },
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today, myCustomButton',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'listYear,dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay, timeGridDay', // timeGridWeek,timeGridDay
    },
    dayHeaders : true, // ? Whether the day headers should appear. For the Month, TimeGrid, and DayGrid views.
    dayHeaderFormat : { weekday: 'short' },
    initialDate: '{{ $select_year ?? 0}}-{{ str_pad($select_month+1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) ?? 0}}-01',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    dayMaxEventRows: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    views: {
        timeGrid: {
            dayMaxEventRows: 2,
        },
        dayGridMonth: {
            editable: false,
            dayMaxEventRows: 2,
        }
    },

    events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {    //get data from db for selected dates
       ...
```

Invalid dayMaxEventRows definition or conflicts with other properties?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take a look at UPDATED # 1 part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the fact that you defined `dayMaxEvents` and `dayMaxEventRows` as global options overrides the view-specific definitions of the same options. So it's using the global options everywhere.

If you comment the global options out and just leave the view-specific ones then it will implement those rules:

```
views: {
    timeGrid: {
        dayMaxEventRows: 2,
    },
    dayGridMonth: {
        editable: false,
        dayMaxEventRows: 2,
    }
},
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKmKzYx